# In meteor app how to add orgin=* in cordova config.xml?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I am new to meteor. I am developing mobile app with meteor. I need to add `<access origin="*"/>` in config.xml I am using google API works fine in browser. But when I run in android device, console throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`. I think the problem is cordova blocks google api. How should I add access origin from meteor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a mobile-config.js file in your root meteor project. Read https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs

You can add an origin wildcard like so.

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

This will add the following to your config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

The following is from: https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-accessRule

> **App.accessRule(domainRule, [options])**
>
> Set a new access rule based on origin domain for your app. By default
>   your application has a limited list of servers it can contact. Use
>   this method to extend this list.
>
> **Default access rules:**
>
> - tel:*, geo:*, mailto:*, sms:*, market:* are allowed and launch    externally (phone app, or an email client on Android)
> - gap:*, cdv:*, file: are allowed (protocols required to access local    file-system) http://meteor.local/* is allowed (a domain Meteor uses
>     to access app's assets)
> - The domain of the server passed to the build process (or local ip    address in the development mode) is used to be able to contact the
>     Meteor app server.
>
> Read more about domain patterns in [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).
>
> Starting with Meteor 1.0.4 access rule for all domains and protocols
>   () is no longer set by default due to [certain
>   kind of possible attacks](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html).
>
> *Arguments*
>
> **domainRule** String - The pattern defining affected domains or URLs.
>
> *Options*
>
> **launchExternal** Boolean - Set to true if the matching URL should be handled externally (e.g. phone app or email client on Android).

Comment: The documentation is a killer!

Comment: Documentation link out of date, unable to find updated reference.

Comment: For anyone who comes after me; I'm pretty sure you're looking for [this](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#accessing-local-files).  That anchor is currently broken, but it will take you to the right view -- just look under the "Domain whitelisting" heading.

Comment: The statement in the documentation says `<access origin="*"/>` is not set by default. But actually it IS set in the config.xml while I didn't set it by myself.
Does anyone know why or how I can remove that?