# Meteor.js Cordova Error: ERROR whitelist rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, meteor, meteor-cordova

When running a Meteor.js Cordova iOS app on the iPhone, some of the images in the app do not load and the XCode console shows the error

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net.....
```

How can we add some/all domains to the whitelist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
App.accessRule('*');  // add this to your mobile-config.js
```

You will need to kill and rebuild your meteor project

```
meteor run ios-device
```

See related question for more details:
[In meteor app how to add orgin=* in cordova config.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279287/in-meteor-app-how-to-add-orgin-in-cordova-config-xml)

Comment: I already had this in my mobile-config, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From XCode, open the Resources folder and you'll find yourapp-Info.plist. Open the plist file then under the App Transport Security Settings dictionary, add a new boolean key, 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' (this should auto-fill as you type) and set value to 'YES'.
Alternatively,still within the App Transport Security dictionary, there's another dictionary called Exception domains, they have localhost listed there, you can use that as a template to add other domains.