# Meteor run ios-device

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am running into problems when I try `meteor run ios-device`

The first error I encountered was this error message:

`Meteor.js Cordova Error: ERROR whitelist rejection`

I solved it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305109/meteor-js-cordova-error-error-whitelist-rejection). I created `mobile-config.js` in my root folder, and added the line:

`App.accessRule('*');`

That error went away, but another error came up.

```
Finished load of: http://meteor.local/
Uncaught Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'Package['service-configuration'].ServiceConfiguration'):191:
http://meteor.local/packages/accounts-base.js?7c29db5c21a76726509bb6bb2a68a2b4b1ecf657
```

And I am stuck. `meteor run ios` works fine. I tried going to `http://meteor.local/packages/accounts-base.js?7c29db5c21a76726509bb6bb2a68a2b4b1ecf657` from browser and there was nothing there. If `meteor.local` is replaced with `localhost:3000`, the page loads on my browser.

I would appreciate any help!
**EDIT:** this also went away, but now the app just hangs at the loading screen.

Last few lines of logs:

```
METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
Resetting plugins due to page load.
METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG loading filepath: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxx/Library/NoCloud/meteor/xx/ for path: %2F
```

Has anyone encountered it?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with my app hanging on the load screen on mobile devices and I fixed it by moving the client and server directories into the root of the application directory: instead of ./my_app/app/client I used ./my_app/client.

Comment: This implies that the problem was fixed by adjusting the load order. Folders that are more deeply nested are loaded first. See here:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fileloadorder
Quote:
There are several load ordering rules. They are applied sequentially to all applicable files in the application, in the priority given below:

1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

Answer (score 0):

I had:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    dataReadyHold = LaunchScreen.hold();

    Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
    Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound');
}
```

Commenting out the line with 'dataReadyHold' did the trick, even though, once started, the app loaded the required data just fine.